# Gameobjects position change with resolution

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a scene with multiple GameObjects with x-y-z position. I'm in 2D so the z is not used.

For now, I worked with the resolution 1024/768 and when I add a GameObject like :

```
GameObject star = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Sphere);
Vector3 position = new Vector3 (x, y, z);
star.transform.localPosition = position;
```

It's ok, the GameObject is in the right position on my scene.

But nox, I'm trying to change the resolution (1920/1080) and all my GameObjects are moved far on the top right, out of my camera.

What's the problem ? How can I fix this ?

For me, when I change the resolution, the 0-0-0 change for my GameObjects....and something weird, If my GameObject has a LineRenderer with positions, they are good on all resolutions...

Edit : This is the function I use for generate my GameObjects, it's a galaxy generator :

```
             for(int i = 0; i < numberOfStars; i++) {
                bool checkPosition = false;

                while (!checkPosition) {
                    // Choose a distance from the center of the galaxy.
                    float distance = Random.Range(5.0f, (float) galaxySize / 2 - 5);

                    // Choose an angle between 0 and 2 * PI.
                    float angle = Random.Range(0.0f, 100.0f) * 2 * Mathf.PI;

                    Vector3 position = new Vector3 (Mathf.Cos (angle) * distance, Mathf.Sin(angle) * distance, 9);

                    if (! Physics.CheckSphere(position, 1)) {
                        GameObject star = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Sphere);
                        star.AddComponent<SolarSystem>();

                        star.name = i + "_" + PlanetNameGenerator.GenerateName();
                        star.GetComponent<SolarSystem>().name = i + "_" + PlanetNameGenerator.GenerateName();

                        star.transform.parent = GameObject.Find ("Targets").transform;

                        // On change le scale en random
                        float randomScale = Random.Range (0f, 0.5f);
                        star.transform.localScale += new Vector3(randomScale,randomScale,randomScale);

                        star.transform.localPosition = position;
                        star.tag = "SolarSystem";

                        checkPosition = true;
                    }
                }
            }
```

This is the scene I see in 1024/768, with my Sphere GameObjects and in pink LineRenderer between them : [image]

This is what I see in 1920/1080, LineRenderer are always in the same position, but GameObjects move away : [image]

Comment: Can you provide more code? also provide whether you are using a perspective or orthographic camera, and how are you changing the resolution?

Comment: More code like what ? I'm using a perspective camera, and I change the resolution in the editor, in the game view

Comment: Show all the code up the point where this is called and the entire function this is in.  With what you provided I wouldn't be able to reproduce your error.

Comment: I edited with my function for generate all GameObjects, do you want more ? If yes, like what ? :)

Comment: I added 2 screens ;)

Comment: This is indeed interesting, I am assuming this function is only called once, Is your line rendering happening in an update?  Also can you check to make sure you camera position isn't moving on the resize?

Comment: I run my function for generate GameObjects and for draw Lines in Awake(). My camera don't change if I change the resolution

Comment: Alright, this conversation is getting long and it wants us to take it to chat, I however can't chat for 5 more hours, but can you move your lineRendering into an update instead of awake so their locations will update on the resize?  Does this also have the same affect if you start at the new resolution?

Comment: It's the same If I start directly in 1920/1080

Comment: I think your positons are out of range. What happens if you reduce the value of distance: Vector3 position = new Vector3 (Mathf.Cos (angle) * distance, Mathf.Sin(angle) * distance, 9);?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was this line :

```
star.transform.parent = GameObject.Find ("Targets").transform;
```

I moved the parent out from Canvas, chnage x-y-z positions of "Targets" to 0 et it's ok.